# Loading a level from an array, XNA 4, C#

Tags: c#, arrays, xna, 2d

Hey I was wondering how I would go about coding a way to load and draw a 2d level from a 2d array in XNA 4.

Here is what I have so far.

I am loading my array like this

```
        mapArray = new int[,]
        {
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {2, 0, 0, 2},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 1}
        };
```

Then I get stuck I cannot seem to figure out how to draw the array, I know I need to use a for loop to check through the array but this is my first time working with 2d arrays.

Is there anyone that could explain in detail how I would go about drawing this?

Thanks

-Josh

Comment: If it's a 2D array, you'll probably want to use two `for` loops at some point. (http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array-loop)

Comment: It is a 2d array but how would I go about detecting what number is in which slot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use something like this in order to check for what number is in each slot:  *(Note: This is untested code... but the code's skeleton comes from a tutorial found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array-loop).)*

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        mapArray = new int[,]
        {
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {2, 0, 0, 2},
            {0, 0, 0, 0},
            {1, 1, 1, 1}
        };

        // Get upper bounds for the mapArray.
        int bound0 = mapArray.GetUpperBound(0);
        int bound1 = mapArray.GetUpperBound(1);

        // Use for-loops to iterate over the mapArray elements.
        for (int i=0; i<=bound0; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<=bound1; j++)
            {
                int value = mapArray[i, j];
                Console.WriteLine(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, this code:

- initializes your `mapArray`
- checks for the ends (bounds) of both dimensions of your `mapArray`
- loops through the first dimension of the `mapArray`
- then, while still looping through first dimension, there is a second loop that goes through second dimension of the `mapArray`
- in the middle of both of these loops, your value is found: `int value = mapArray[i, j];`

[Here is a reference](http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array-loop) for 2D array loops for C#.  And [here is a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czz5hkty.aspx) on arrays in C#.  Hope this helps a little!

Comment: I just figured it out using some of the ideas from this code http://www.dotnetperls.com/2d-array-loop Thank you all!!!

Comment: Just edited this answer with some more explanation at the end.  Hope this helps!

Comment: And also, welcome to Stack Overflow, as well! And... just for future reference, if you ever get an answer to your question (that ended up working for you,) don't forget to accept the answer (and/or upvote answers that did help!) :)